# Why does changing maxJumps not have any effect on my jumping?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

For some reason changing maxJumps to any positive number (when set to zero or a negative number the player can't jump at all) still only lets the player jump one time?
This is my code:

```
public float jumpingPower = 16f;
public float maxJumps = 1;
private float currentJumps;
public float coyoteTimerMax = .03f;
private float coyoteTimer;
private float jumpBuffer;
public float maxJumpBuffer = .3f;`
bool newIsGrounded;
```

```
void Update()
    {
       
/// ...
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jumpBuffer = maxJumpBuffer;
        }


        jumpBuffer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (newIsGrounded)
        {
            currentJumps = 0;
            coyoteTimer = coyoteTimerMax;
            dashUsed = 0;

        }
        else
        {
            coyoteTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

        }


        
        if (jumpBuffer > 0 && coyoteTimer > 0 && currentJumps < maxJumps    ||Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && currentJumps > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
            currentJumps++;
            newIsGrounded = false;
            jumpBuffer = 0; // Reset the jump buffer after successfully jumping
    
/// ...
```

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        /// ...

        newIsGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCapsule(groundCheck.position, new Vector2(.999f, .0144f), CapsuleDirection2D.Horizontal, 0, groundLayer);

       /// ...
    }
```

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            newIsGrounded = true;


        }


    }



    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            newIsGrounded = false;


        }


    }
```

I want the current jump variable to go up once after jumping but it only goes up after the first jump mid-air. I need to add a line here because my question is mostly code.

Comment: `currentJumps < maxJumps || Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && currentJumps > 0` This will always be true when maxJumps is >= 1

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided doesn't seem to make you able to jump just once. I think you change your values somewhere else, so that `if condition` with jumping behavior doesn't work.

First change this

```
if (jumpBuffer > 0 && coyoteTimer > 0 && currentJumps < maxJumps    ||Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && currentJumps > 0)
```

to this, because as it was mentioned by someone before, it doesn't make sense.

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && jumpBuffer > 0 && coyoteTimer > 0 && currentJumps < maxJumps)
```

And then try to print those values to check what is not `true`. Additionally, you can provide your full script for us to understand your issue better.